# Unnecessary www to non-www redirect when accessing the website

Tags: apache, nginx, redirect, prestashop, plesk

I have a problem with some additional redirect being added when just accessing the website.

Here's the example:

[image]

But all i need is to www redirect to www/ie/. And for some reason, non-www redirect pops up in the middle.
I'm using plesk with apache and prestashop, but i don't have same issues with non-www websites.
In plesk, www-domain is set as preferable.
Could this be to the fact, that the DNS A record is set for non-www domain? And, therefore, ssl certificate is being issued for non-www domain, that also may cause the redirect?